# Angular, use Redux for managing account balance

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I've been reading about Redux because Im building an app in Angular where users can buy stuff and the price is deducted from his account balance. The user won't interact with other users and the balances are independent from each other, so if one user buys an item it won't be deducted from his balance and credited to others user balance. Also the stock of items is infinite so I won't have to code that, I just need to keep record of what the user bought and his current account balance.

I know that I can do this with Redux, but after some reading one of the things I learned is that you should only use it if it's neccesary and can't be done in an easier way.

So my question: Is it justified to use Redux in this case or is it possible to do this using Angular and Firebase (what I'm currently using as database)? or maybe I should use a nodejs server to manage the account balance?

Comment: are you looking to maintain data across components asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

From their documentation: http://redux.js.org/

> Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps.

This does not sound like what you need if you are looking for a way to more permanently store information for a user. Seems that firebase is more set up for that.

From the firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/

> Store and sync app data in milliseconds.